# Function to delete all occurrences of a word in a sentence in C

Tags: c, string

I have this code which will remove the first occurrence of the word from the sentence:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int delete(char *source, char *word);

void main(void) {

    char sentence[500];
    char word[30];



    printf("Please enter a sentence. Max 499 chars. \n");
    fgets(sentence, 500, stdin);

    printf("Please enter a word to be deleted from sentence. Max 29 chars. \n");
    scanf("%s", word);

    delete(sentence, word);

    printf("%s", sentence);
}


int delete(char *source, char *word) {

    char *p;
    char temp[500], temp2[500];

    if(!(p = strstr(source, word))) {
        printf("Word was not found in the sentence.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    strcpy(temp, source);
    temp[p - source] = '\0';
    strcpy(temp2, p + strlen(word));
    strcat(temp, temp2);    
    strcpy(source, temp);
    return 1;
}
```

How would I modify it to delete all occurrences of the word in the given sentence? Can i still use the strstr function in this case?

Thanks for the help!

Open to completely different ways of doing this too.

P.S. This might sound like a homework question, but it's actually a past midterm question which I'd like to resolve to prepare for my midterm!

As a side question, if I use `fgets(word, 30, stdin)` instead of `scanf("%s", word)`, it no longer works and tells me that the word was not found in the sentence. Why?

Comment: `fgets` will include the newline in the string, while `scanf` won't.

Comment: Fix your code formatting.

Comment: 1) Your function `delete` needs to return 1 at the end.  2) What should your function do if asked to delete "fubar" from "fufubarbar"?

Comment: `Max 500 chars.` 499 chars. `Max 30chars.` 29 chars.

Comment: Thanks interjay, that makes sense. ooga, I think that's fixed now? and that's a good point dbc. Mine returns fubar, but I'm assuming it shouldn't affect the sentence.

Comment: To do what you want, Just do `while (!delete(source,word)){}`. Not super efficient, but i am super lazy.

Comment: Thanks bluepixy, forgot the '\0'. Supposed to use a 30 and 500 char array, so I guess the max is 499 and 29.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams - your algorithm will, when removing "fubar" from "fufubarbar", return an empty string.  Is that what is desired?

Comment: @dbc could be? Depends if the result should include no instances of the given word or not. To address this, i'd modify the return statement to be the first character after the deleted word, then you could do `char* val = source; while (*(source=delete(source,word)));` Again, super lazy!

Comment: @dbc I think it should just return fufubarbar, as the word "fubar" isn't found. Up top I interpreted it as delete any substring occurrence of fubar, but I believe it should delete it only if it's a word, bounded by spaces.

Comment: I think ryyver's answer, with strtok returns what was expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How would I modify it to* ***delete all occurrences of the word*** *in the given sentence?*

There are many ways, as you have suggested, and since you are *Open to completely different ways of doing this too...*
***Here is a different idea***:
A sentence uses white space to separate words.  You can use that to help solve the problem.  Consider implementing these steps using `fgets()`, `strtok()` and `strcat()` to break apart the string, and reassemble it without the *string to remove*.

```
0)  create line buffer sufficient length to read lines from file  
    (or pass in line buffer as an argument)
1)  use while(fgets(...) to get new line from file
2)  create char *buf={0};
3)  create char *new_str; (calloc() memory to new_str >= length of line buffer) 
4)  loop on buf = strtok();, using " \t\n" as the delimiter
Inside loop:
    a. if (strcmp(buf, str_to_remove) != 0) //approve next token for concatenation
            { strcat(new_str, buf); strcat(new_str, " ");}//if not str_to_remove, 
                                                  //concatenate token, and a space
5)  free allocated memory
```

`new_str` now contains sentence without occurrences of str_to_remove.

***Here is a demo*** using this set of steps (pretty much)

```
int delete(char *str, char *str_to_remove)
{
    char *buf;
    char *new_str;

    new_str = calloc(strlen(str)+1, sizeof(char));

    buf = strtok(str, " \t\n");
    while(buf)
    {
        if(strcmp(buf, str_to_remove) != 0)
        {
            strcat(new_str, buf);
            strcat(new_str, " ");
        }
        buf = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    }
    printf("%s\n", new_str);
    free(new_str);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    delete("this sentence had a withh bad withh word", "withh");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey ryyker! Been trying to implement what you suggested with strtok. thank you for providing your demo, it really helps. Running your code as is gives me a seg fault though, but the idea's there! Thx!

Comment: I actually ran it with several test strings before posting it.  Can you use your debugger to see where seg-fault is occurring.

Comment: make sure you are allocating enough space to new_str.   I used `strlen(str)+1` which, considering we are removing stuff from original string, should always be sufficient.

Comment: Compiler gives me the following warnings:
206-2k14mid_v5.c: In function ‘delete’:
206-2k14mid_v5.c:9:15: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘calloc’ [enabled by default]
     new_str = calloc(strlen(str)+1, sizeof(char));
               ^
206-2k14mid_v5.c:22:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘free’ [enabled by default]
     free(new_str);

Comment: Sorry have to go to a meeting, will return shortly (cannot see your warnings yet...)

Comment: Wow sorry for that, don't know how to put a newline in comments. Not sure how to use gdb either for debug...

Comment: nope didn't change anything. Your code makes perfect sense though, and seems to me the best solution, as it doesn't delete substrings but rather words. I just don't get why it's seg faulting. Why would you use " \t\n" instead of just " " as the delimiter?

Comment: Ok, it works, as long as I pass in a a pre-allocated string to the delete function, instead of inputting the string directly between quotes. Thank you so much ryyver. P.S. Compiler warnings were just because I didn't include stdlib.h ...

Comment: I'm back.  Good to hear you got it figured out!  I used " \t\n" instead of just " " because tabs and new lines are considered white space, and can be used as delimeters.  Actually though, "\n" in retrospect gets consumed by `fgets()`, so should not be in there.  However, it did not hurt in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t delete( char *source, const char *word ) 
{
    size_t n = strlen( word );
    size_t count = 0;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        char *p = source;

        while ( ( p = strstr( p, word ) ) != NULL ) 
        {
            char *t = p;
            char *s = p + n;
            while ( ( *t++ = *s++ ) );
            ++count; 
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "abxabyababz";

    printf( "%zu\n", delete( s, "ab" ) );
    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
4
xyz
```

As for the question about `fgets` then it includes the new line character in the string. You have to remove it from the string.